# Redirects to external URL - WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to optimize MySQL queries, so I have replaced query:

```
echo wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=3");
```

with:

```
$sidebar_menu = get_transient( 'sidebar_menu' );
if( $sidebar_menu === false ) {
    $sidebar_menu = wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=3&echo=0");
    set_transient( 'sidebar_menu', $sidebar_menu, 60*60*24 );
}
echo $sidebar_menu;
```

But something weird is happening, after I return after 20 sec again in website and click on one of the links in sidebar, redirects me to the: [financedaily.co/work-at-home-mom-true-success-story/](http://financedaily.co/work-at-home-mom-true-success-story/)

Do you have any idea what is going on and how can I optimize the wp_list_pages query ? I am using shared hosting from [icnhost.net](http://icnhost.net)

Also when I activete W3TotalCache plugin, redirects all the pages on external URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the plugins on the client theme was hacked. I found that with WordFence. Plugin required a jQuery library and it was requiring on custom URL which sometimes sends to you jQuery library but sometimes redirects you to an ad page. I have resolved that using the WordPress plugin called WordFence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it's possible that there is an issue related to optimizing a query that sends you to some wierd specific site? You have a some kind virus on your site, or at least some specific code which does this.

Comment: I create a database backup in the godaddy hosting and everything is working well.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Export database and the theme files and moved in a host in godaddy.com. The website is working well and there is not any CPU Usage

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a browser hack. I have found a site that offers advice and software to remove this and other browser hacks.

Here is their advice on how to remove Smarter-finance-daily.com from Mozilla Firefox

•At the top of the Firefox window, click the Firefox button, go over to the Help sub-menu and select Troubleshooting Information.
•To continue, click Reset Firefox in the confirmation window that opens. It will close and be reset.
•When it’s done, a window will list the information that was imported. Click Finish and Firefox will open.

Here is the link to their site: I DO NOT ENDORSE ANY SOFTWARE NOR ADVICE.

http://www.repairtoolbar.com/how-to-clean-smarter-finance-daily-com-from-firefoxremoval-instructions/